# Swift - sorting and separating array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

Is there a way to efficiently sort an array of dictionaries based on a parameter value AND return separate arrays for each of these parameter values?

Example Array:

```
[["value":3, "groupID":1],
["value":5, "groupID":2],
["value":2, "groupID":1],
["value":6, "groupID":3],
["value":1, "groupID":2],
["value":9, "groupID":3]]
```

Desired return output 1 (sorted array):

```
[["value":2, "groupID":1],
["value":3, "groupID":1],
["value":1, "groupID":2],
["value":5, "groupID":2],
["value":6, "groupID":3],
["value":9, "groupID":3]]
```

Desired return output 2 (separated arrays by parameter):

```
[["value":2, "groupID":1],
["value":3, "groupID":1]]

[["value":1, "groupID":2],
["value":5, "groupID":2]]

[["value":6, "groupID":3],
["value":9, "groupID":3]]
```

One solution I've come up with is quite slow, which is:

```
//variable array is the master array of dictionaries

var sorted = [[Int:Int]]() 
//(Output 1) sorted is the sorted array
sorted = array.sorted { t1, t2 in
                if t1.groupID == t2.groupID {
                    return t1.value < t2.value
                }
                return t1.groupID < t2.groupID
            }

var separated = [Int:[Int:Int]]() 
//(Output 2) separated is a dictionary that contains separate arrays, all of which have the same of a designated property. Essentially the same thing as separate, distinct arrays sorted by parameter for Output 2
separated = [
            for i in 0..<sorted.count {
                separated[sorted[i].channel]?.append(sorted[i])
            }
```

Any thought on how to make this faster? Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what output 2 even means, because it is three things, not one thing.

Comment: Output 1 is a return of one single array. Output 2 is a return of three separate arrays. I'm looking for a function that can quickly and simultaneously output both Outputs 1 and 2 (one large single array and then a set of separated arrays).

Comment: I don’t get what means. A function has one output.

Comment: You can have multi output functions in swift....
Ex:
func abc() -> ([Int],[String])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple one-liner approach that might get you started:

```
let d = Dictionary.init(grouping: array) {$0["groupID"]!}
```

The result is a *dictionary* keyed by the value of the groupIDs:

```
["1": [["groupID": "1", "value": "3"], ["groupID": "1", "value": "2"]],
 "2": [["groupID": "2", "value": "5"], ["groupID": "2", "value": "1"]],  
 "3": [["groupID": "3", "value": "6"], ["groupID": "3", "value": "9"]]]
```

Well, think about that result. The *values* of the dictionary are your three "desired output" arrays:

```
[["value":"2", "groupID":"1"],
["value":"3", "groupID":"1"]]

[["value":"1", "groupID":"2"],
["value":"5", "groupID":"2"]]

[["value":"6", "groupID":"3"],
["value":"9", "groupID":"3"]]
```

You can access the values as the `values` of the dictionary, or you can use the `keys` to sort by key and then dive in for each array.

Deriving the *single* sorted array is trivial.

Comment: This is great. It is an elegant one liner use after obtaining the single sorted array, and operates MUCH faster than my original implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a beautiful implementation, looks like it works, but not sure if faster than yours:

```
let array: [[String: String]] = [["value":"3", "groupID":"1"],
             ["value":"5", "groupID":"2"],
             ["value":"2", "groupID":"1"],
             ["value":"6", "groupID":"3"],
             ["value":"1", "groupID":"2"],
             ["value":"9", "groupID":"3"]]

// grouping
var dict: [String: [[String: String]]] = [:]
array.forEach { (element) in
    var elements: [[String: String]] = []
    let groupID = element["groupID"]!
    if dict.keys.contains(groupID) {
        elements = dict[groupID]!
    }
    elements.append(element)
    dict[groupID] = elements
}

// spliting and sorting
var final: [[String: [[String: String]]]] = []
dict.keys.sorted().forEach { (key) in
    let sorted = dict[key]!.sorted(by: { $0["value"]! < $1["value"]! })
    final.append([key: sorted])
}

print(final)
```